# syncfusion_flutter_datepicker calendar display messed up

Tags: flutter, calendar, syncfusion, syncfusion-calendar, flutter-pubspec

i am using date range picker for quite a time now but since 2-3 days i am facing a very strange issue regardless of the version I change.
Even if i add the very basic code from your site -

Positioned(
left: 20,
top: 50,
right: 20,
bottom: 50,
child:
Container(
color: Colors.white,
height: screenWidth/2,
width: screenWidth/2,
child: Center(
child: SfDateRangePicker(
onSelectionChanged: _onSelectionChanged,
selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.range,
initialSelectedRange: PickerDateRange(
DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 4)),
DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 3))),
),
),
),
),

i am getting calendrer like this either using directly or in container.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n38Ry.jpg)

Please let me know any possible reason and solution for this.

trying to display proper calendar in flutter app.

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I could fix it by implementing my own `cellBuilder` parameter in the `SfDateRangePicker` like the following

```dart
cellBuilder: (BuildContext context,
    DateRangePickerCellDetails details) {
  
  // box decoration if selected
  BoxDecoration? boxDecoration;
  // set the style of the text accordingly
  var style = _normalTextStyle;

  // All dates before initDate, convert them to grey (not allowed to choose)
  if (isLowerDate(
      details.date, DateTime.now())) {
    style = _greyTextStyle;
  } else if (isSameDate(
      details.date, DateTime.now())) {
    boxDecoration = BoxDecoration(
        border:
            Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle);
  }
  return Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
    decoration: boxDecoration,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment:
          MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(details.date.day.toString(),
            style: style)
      ],
    ),
  );
},
```

where

```dart
const _normalTextStyle = TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 85, 85, 85));

const _greyTextStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.grey);

bool isLowerDate(DateTime dt1, DateTime dt2) {
  return ((getDateWithoutTime(dt1).difference(getDateWithoutTime(dt2))).inDays < 0);
}

DateTime getDateWithoutTime(DateTime d) {
  return DateTime(
      d.year, d.month, d.day);
}
```

You will end up building something not so beautiful like this:

[image: results implementing your own cellBuilder]

If you want to modify the selected dates shape, border radious, color, etc. to have a nicer view, you will have to go further and create a `DateRangePickerController`, assign it in the `controller` parameter, and use this controller to access the selected date cell inside the `cellBuilder` by checking `details.date` is equal to `_controller.selectedDate` and modify the BoxDecoration property of the container accordingly. Don't forget to change the `SfDateRangePicker` parameter to `selectionColor: Colors.transparent,` otherwise, when changing the `boxDecoration` cell of the selected dates in the `cellBuilder` you will still have the blue squared box over there.

I hope this can help you. Here are some resources about it:

https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/daterangepicker/builders